# How do I call PL/SQL variables from within a Javascript function?

Tags: javascript, oracle, google-maps, plsql, oracle-apex

I would like to display coordinates - retrieved from an Oracle database - as markers on a Google Map by calling pl/sql variables from within a javascript function. This is all done in APEX 5. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

What works: I select `GEOMETRY` (SDO_GEOMETRY) in the `PHOTO` table into `l_lng` (longitude) and `l_lat` (latitude) variables:

```
SELECT t.x Longitude,
  t.y Latitude
FROM photo,
  TABLE(sdo_util.getvertices(photo.geometry)) t;
```

Using `DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(l_lng);` and `DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(l_lat);`, I can see that `l_lng` and `l_lat` successfully stored the values because the output is:

```
-4.083714
50.315475
```

Specifically, the javascript variable `myLatLng` needs to pull the coordinates from `l_lng` and `l_lat`.

```
var myLatLng = {lat: l_lat, lng: l_lng};
```

My full code:

```
DECLARE

l_lng NUMBER;
l_lat NUMBER;


begin

SELECT t.x Longitude,
  t.y Latitude 
  INTO l_lng, l_lat
FROM photo,
  TABLE(sdo_util.getvertices(photo.geometry)) t
  WHERE photo.id=39;


htp.print('

<html>

<head>
    <style>
        #map {
            width: 500px;
            height: 400px;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    <script>
        function initialize() {

                var myLatLng = {
                    lat: l_lat,
                    lng: l_lng
                };



                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
                    zoom: 17,
                    center: myLatLng
                });
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myLatLng,
                    map: map,
                    title: 'Hello World!'
               });
        }



    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
</body>

</html>

');
end;
```

As suggested by @vmachan, I modified my ht.print statement to read:

```
htp.print('<html>');
htp.print('<head>');
htp.print('<style>
    #map {
        width: 500px;
        height: 400px;
        }
    </style>
');

htp.print('<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_lng" VALUE="'||l_lng||'">');
htp.print('<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_lat" VALUE="'||l_lat||'">');
htp.print(' 

    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    <script>
        function initialize() {

                var myLatLng = {
                    lat: p_lat,
                    lng: p_lng
                };



                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
                    zoom: 17,
                    center: myLatLng
                });
        }
    </script>
');
htp.print('</head>');
htp.print('
    <body>
        <div id="map"></div>
    </body>
');
htp.print('</html>');
```

Comment: I think you would need to break up the htp.print statement into multiples and then concatenate the lat, long values to your HTML. This [example](http://authors.phptr.com/boardman/solutions/instruct.html) should help you, scroll to the instruct_personal_info PROCEDURE.. to see how it is done in that example

Comment: Thanks, I'm having a read now - looks helpful so far!

Comment: @vmachan I used your link - I believe I have done the right thing (the code validates and if I change the input type to `text`, it prints the correct coordinates on the page), but the map does not display though. It works if I hard code the coordinates to `myLatLng` like so:
`var myLatLng = {
                        lng: -4.083714,
                        lat: 50.315475
                    };`
 suggesting that the javascript is not picking up the values!

I'll add my htp.print statement to my question.

Comment: You are outputting the values in text input elements, not as javascript variables.  Either write code to extract the value from the input element into the javascript variables or output it as javascript to start with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a snippet that I think if applied would work, this is what I was trying to suggest in my comment earlier.

```
htp.print('<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script>
    function initialize() {

            var myLatLng = {
                lat: ' || l_lng || ',
                lng: ' || l_lat || '
            };

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
                zoom: 17,
                center: myLatLng
            });
    }
</script>');
```

You would need to address the string continuation on multiple lines when sending to htp.print, or just concatenate the whole html into one line which would work but may not be very readable.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It really did help thanks! Is it a simple task to do the opposite? In another part of my app I am using [Google's Geolocation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation) to get current location, and I need to take those coordinates and assign them to an item in my application.

Comment: You mean take the items from Javascript and send it to the database? Unclear from your comment, could you elaborate?

Comment: Assuming it's the best way, to take the lat and lng coordinates from JavaScript and assign them to PL/SQL variables which can in turn be used to set the value of a text field in the application.

Comment: I think one way that usually works is call a stored procedure or SQL statement and send the Javascript values as parameters to it and then let the SQL update the underlying tables which can be used by other parts of your application.

Comment: Thank you, I'll give that a whirl.

Answer (score 0):

You are outputting the values in text input elements, not as javascript variables. Either write code to extract the value from the input element into the javascript variables or output it as javascript to start with. Replace:

```
htp.print('<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_lng" VALUE="'||l_lng||'">');
htp.print('<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_lat" VALUE="'||l_lat||'">');
```

with

```
htp.print('var p_lng='||l_lng||';');
htp.print('var p_lat='||l_lat||''');
```