# How can i call a PL-SQL procedure inside a Javascript function?

Tags: javascript, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, server-side

I have written a pl sql procedure which updates a column in the ATP Database table. The procedure is as follows -

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE updateFlag(   
p_unique_id in table.UNIQUE_ID%TYPE)  
IS  
BEGIN  
UPDATE table SET enabled_flag = 'Y' WHERE unique_id = p_unique_id;  
COMMIT;  
END;  
/
```

I want to call this procedure inside a Javascript function because this procedure should be called only if another function returns success. Is there any way to call a PL-SQL procedure inside a JS function?
(the database being used is ATP Database and the application is built using Visual Builder Cloud Services)

Comment: Are you just looking for [a Node package for accessing Oracle](https://www.npmjs.com/package/oracledb)?

Comment: one way would be your js to call out to a REST API that fires the procedure. Autonomous Database makes it easy to expose your plsql program via REST API.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith yeah thats one way but since i am using Visual Builder Cloud Services (VBCS), i cannot make a call to REST API in between the function. i need to make the call before or after the function or else ill have to modify the whole function.

Comment: You may try reference from Link(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34534653/how-do-i-call-pl-sql-variables-from-within-a-javascript-function)